# Postgresql about encoding error

Tags: postgresql

I met the encoding error.

```
sudo su - postgres
psql
```

Then I met:

> psql (9.2.18)
>
> 頛詨o "help" 憿舐內隤芣???

This is not the real Chinese word.

So I do the following in the psql:

```
postgres=# SET client_encoding = 'BIG5';
SET
```

But when I do the following is still error:

```
\q
psql
```

> psql (9.2.18)
>
> 頛詨o "help" 憿舐內隤芣???

Answer (score 0):

The setting that determines which language `psql` uses is the `LC_MESSAGES` environment variable.

You can modify that to get a different language.

If you like the language, but the message looks wrong to you, it could be that the font you are using does not contain the displayed character.